# Converse of ratio test?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My question is this

> If $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n4^n$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n(-2)^n$ converges?

I know this can be provd by using radius of convergence. But someone gave the following

> As $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n4^n$ converges, by ratio test, for sufficiently large $n$ we have $$\left|\frac{c_{n+1}4^{n+1}}{c_n4^n}\right|\le 1.$$
>   Thus we have
>   $$\left|\frac{c_{n+1}(-2)^{n+1}}{c_n(-2)^n}\right|\le\frac{1}{2}.$$
>   Again using ratio test, we have that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_n(-2)^n$ converges.

Is this possible? Since I've never heard about the converse of ratio test I'm not sure this is right or not.

Comment: This would not be the converse of the Ratio Test, for the record. But yes, this is true, since $|\sum c_n (-2)^n| \le |\sum c_n 4^n|$ and the latter satisfies the Cauchy Criterion, we can say the former does as well.

Comment: Suppose $c_{2n}=4^{-2n}\cdot 3^{-2n}$ and $ c_{2n+1}=2\cdot 4^{-2n-1}\cdot 3^{-2n}. $Then $\sum_nc_n4^n$ converges but $c_{2n+1}4^{2n+1}>c_{2n}4^{2n}>0$ for all $ n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is true, but your friends argument is unsound. It is possible
for $\sum_n a_n$ to converge absolutely but for $|a_{n+1}|>|a_n|$
infinitely often.

A sound argument is to note that $\sum c_n4^n$ convergent, means that
$|c_n 4^n|$ is bounded, by $M$ say, and then $|c_n(-2)^n|\le M/2^n$.